# Converting Objective-C to Swift 3.1 error with unresolved identifier

Tags: objective-c, swift, selector

In my ongoing project to convert one of my published objective-c apps to Swift 3.1, I am running into another issue. I am using a selector to call a function in my appdelegate, but in swift it's giving me an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'reachabilityChanged'

The function 'reachabilityChanged' does exist, but it seems that swift is not finding it. Below is the code in swift and objective-c that I am using. The reachabilityChanged function in swift is not giving any errors. And of course this is working fine in objective-c since I am converting a published app. I am going through some tutorials in swift 3.1, so I'm not sure if my syntax is correct.

```
//SWIFT 3.1
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(reachabilityChanged), //getting 'use of unresolved identifier reachabilityChanged' for the reachabilityChanged function
name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kReachabilityChangedNotification), 
object: nil)

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
//code
}

//OBJ-C
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: 
@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note {
//code
}
```

Comment: Typo? `#selector(reachabilityChanged(note:))`

Comment: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: Oh, didn't realize there was a swift version of Reachability. I should have checked tho. This may be helpful. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kReachabilityChangedNotification),  object: nil)
```

Note : `#selector(self.reachabilityChanged(note:))` - `self` as well as `(note:)`

Also add @objc as Mr. Hedgehog mentioned.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `)`?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for observation

Comment: I made the changes, but still no bueno. Swift doesn't like the objc in the beginning of a function stating 'can only be used with classes, objc protocols...' and swift directs me to delete it. The adding of the self and note: parameter didn't help either. Still getting the unresolved identifier. Thanks for the suggestions anyways.

Comment: Can you provide more context then? Where do you assign Observer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@objc` before `func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification)`

Comment: While this is missing, I don't think this is the root of the "unresolved identifier" compiler message. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This hope it work for You:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doThisWhenNotify), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "myNotificationKey"), object: nil)

func doThisWhenNotify(note: NSNotification) {
    print("VC1")
    lblTest.text="Its Notification"
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from asked question?

Comment: sorry  my English is weak  i did not got the question i thought his code is not working so i paste mine